# Why my StringReader is emptied after new XPathDocument(strReader) ?

Tags: c#, xml, stringreader

I am curious why would my `StringReader` is emptied after I call something like this :

```
        XPathDocument xPathDoc;
        StringReader strReader = new StringReader(l_xmlFile.content);
        xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(strReader);
```

`l_xmlFile.content` is a string and is properly loaded to `xPathDoc` but after the last line of this code `strReader` (namely its `_s` member) is null and length is 0. Why is it happening ? Nothing about this is mentioned on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa336088%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty common behavior in .NET, the XPathDocument object takes ownership of the input object.  And calls its Dispose() method after it completed reading it.  It is StringReader.Dispose() that resets the internal `_s` and `_length` Fields.

The MSDN documentation for the XPathDocument(TextReader) constructor is pretty clumsy but could be interpreted to say so.

Comment: So how can I reassign it ? This: strReader = l_xmlFile.content; simply won't work. And StringReader doesn't have many methods to choose from.

Comment: What about  for instance:         // Summary:
        //     Creates an object that contains all the relevant information required to
        //     generate a proxy used to communicate with a remote object.
        public virtual ObjRef CreateObjRef(Type requestedType);

Comment: Why do you have to reassign it?  Why doesn't using `strReader = new StringReader(l_xmlFile.content)` again work?  What remoting has to do with this is also wildly unguessable.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN:

> After the TextReader object has been used to load XML data, the cursor of the TextReader 
>   object is positioned at the end of the data. The TextReader object must be reset to read 
>   through the data again.

Does that answer it?